# Need help to modify JS for loop

Tags: javascript

Edited: New to coding. I’m copying and adjusting code from a simple JavaScript project, and here is the for loop I need to modify:

```
randomize(ShipClass = Ship) {
    this.removeAllShips();

    for (let size = 5; size >=2; size--) {
        for (let n = 0; n < 6 - size; n++) {
            const direction = getRandomFrom("row", "column");
            const ship = new ShipClass(size, direction);

            while (!ship.placed) {
                const x = getRandomBetween(0, 9);
                const y = getRandomBetween(0, 9);

                this.removeShip(ship);
                this.addShip(ship, x, y);
            }
        }
```

It randomly places 10 ships with the following sizes: {2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5}.

I need to modify it so that it places only 5 ships with the following sizes: **{2,3,3,4,5}**.

Comment: Why not iterate over an array w/ the ships and their sizes?

Comment: Unrelated, bu why would you need to call `this.removeShip(ship)` when you have just created that `ship` instance and verified it is not "placed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over your desired sizes array with a `for..of` loop:

```
randomize(ShipClass = Ship) {
    this.removeAllShips();

    for (let size of [2, 3, 3, 4, 5]) {
        const direction = getRandomFrom("row", "column");
        const ship = new ShipClass(size, direction);
    
        while (!ship.placed) {
            const x = getRandomBetween(0, 9);
            const y = getRandomBetween(0, 9);
    
            this.removeShip(ship);
            this.addShip(ship, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```